# fullcalendar error while sending/taking JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I am trying to make a one page CRUD application using FullCalendar. Actually, I did. I'm just getting errors when I create events and then delete them. When my application is clicked on an existing event, it has to be deleted. But I get the error shown below.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTZsr.png)

and it is my event object.
[Event object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USvvl.png)

Would you help me figure out what the problem is?

The javascript code is like below:

```js
var teacher_id = 2;

function addEventToDB(teacher_name,teacher_id,title,start,end,color){

axios.post('events', {
    teacher_name: teacher_name,
    user_id: teacher_id,
    title: title,
    start: start,
    end: end,
    color: color
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

}

function deleteEventFromDB (event_id,teacher_name) {
    axios.delete('/events/'+ event_id)
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    });
}

var eventType = 'Individual';
var eventTitle = 'Available for Individual';
var eventColor = 'orange';

$(function () {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotEventOverlap: false,
        slotDuration: '00:30:00',
        slotLabelInterval: "01:00",
        scrollTime: '08:00:00',
        events: 'events',
        //defaultTimedEventDuration:  '00:30:00',

        footer: {
            center: 'eventTypeButton'
        },
        
        customButtons: {
            eventTypeButton: {
                text: 'Event type Toggle Button (Group/Individual)',
                click: function() {
                    if(eventType=='Individual') {
                        eventType = 'Group';
                        eventTitle = 'Available for Group';
                        eventColor = 'blue';
                    } else {
                        eventType = 'Individiual';
                        eventTitle = 'Available for Individual';
                        eventColor = 'orange';
                    }
                        
                }
            }
        },

        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            end = date.clone();
            end = end.add(30,'minutes');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                title: eventTitle,
                teacher : teacher_id,
                teacher_name: teacher_name, 
                start: date.format(),
                end: end.format(),
                allDay: false,
                color: eventColor
            });
            var title = eventTitle;
            var start = date.format();
            var end = end.format();
            var color = eventColor;
            var teacher_name = "{{ Auth::user()->name }}";
            addEventToDB(teacher_name,teacher_id,title, start, end, color);
            
        },

        
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
            console.log(event.id);
            deleteEventFromDB(event.id,event.teacher_name);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event.id);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
        },

    })

});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">My calendar</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am adding server code (I am using Laravel 5.6):

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\AvailableTime;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
class AvailableTimeController extends Controller
{
public function index(Authenticatable $user)
{   
if($user->hasRole('admin') || $user->hasRole('superadmin')){
    return AvailableTime::all(); 
} else if( $user->hasRole('teacher')) {
    return AvailableTime::where('user_id',$user->id)->get();  
}
}
public function show($id)
{
return AvailableTime::findOrFail($id);
}
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
$AvailableTime = AvailableTime::findOrFail($id);
$AvailableTime->update($request->all());
return $AvailableTime;
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
$AvailableTime = AvailableTime::create($request->all());
return $AvailableTime;
}
public function destroy($id)
{   
try {
$availableTime = AvailableTime::find($id);
$availableTime->delete();
return 'Deleted Successfully';
}
catch ( \Exception $e) {
return redirect()->route('show_calendar')->withErrors 
'JSONError' => "Event can not be deleted"
]);
}
}
}
```

Comment: I think event object does not have a property called 'id'. Can you show us the event object that is coming to eventClick() function?

Comment: This isn’t a JavaScript error, it’s a server error. What’s the response from the server for that request?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards look closely though, the URL being called is "events/undefined" ...so yeah the server will undoubtedly crash because it was clearly supposed to go to "events/1" or something like that. The root cause is that the event object doesn't have an ID. Since `event_id` is undefined, this is what gets appended to the URL. The server crash is merely a symptom of that.

Comment: Hayreddin, we don't know your JSON structure but we have to assume that your events do not have any "id" property when you add them to fullCalendar. We can tell this because in JavaScript a variable will be printed as "undefined" if it does not exist. This means your URL for deleting is being created incorrectly. You need to either construct your event objects to include an "id" property

Comment: Thanks for the update, but this is not the problematic part of the code. Showing the code which generates the event JSON in the first place would be more useful. You need to change it to supply your events with an "id" property which is the ID of the event in the database, so you can use it for updating and deleting later

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your interests, But, normally, it works. If I add the data afterwards and then delete it quickly, the application gives me error. Normally, event object has id, I updated my question giving my event object example and server side code

Comment: Well, this is because your process for adding events is flawed - you're adding an event to the calendar without waiting for the server to send you a valid ID for it. So that event can never be deleted or updated in the server by clicking on it in the calendar. It has no relationship to the event recorded in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your advice and I could develop a solution. In fact, the problem is a synchronization problem, and every time I click to create a new event and I click to delete it, all events are refetched and the problem is solved. I share the codes for solving below.

```js
function addEventToDB(teacher_name,teacher_id,title,start,end,color){

axios.post('events', {
    teacher_name: teacher_name,
    user_id: teacher_id,
    title: title,
    start: start,
    end: end,
    color: color
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    console.log(error);
  });

}

function deleteEventFromDB (event_id,teacher_name) {
    axios.delete('/events/'+ event_id)
    .then(function (response) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    console.log(error);
    });
}

var eventType = 'Individual';
var eventTitle = 'Available for Individual';
var eventColor = 'orange';

$(function () {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotEventOverlap: false,
        slotDuration: '00:30:00',
        slotLabelInterval: "01:00",
        scrollTime: '08:00:00',
        events: 'events',
        //defaultTimedEventDuration:  '00:30:00',

        footer: {
            center: 'eventTypeButton'
        },
        
        customButtons: {
            eventTypeButton: {
                text: 'Event type Toggle Button (Group/Individual)',
                click: function() {
                    if(eventType=='Individual') {
                        eventType = 'Group';
                        eventTitle = 'Available for Group';
                        eventColor = 'blue';
                    } else {
                        eventType = 'Individiual';
                        eventTitle = 'Available for Individual';
                        eventColor = 'orange';
                    }
                        
                }
            }
        },

        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            var end = date.clone();
            end = end.add(30,'minutes');
            var title = eventTitle;
            var start = date.format();
            var endformat = end.format();
            console.log(endformat);
            var color = eventColor;
            var teacher_name = "{{ Auth::user()->name }}";
            addEventToDB(teacher_name,teacher_id,title, start, endformat, color);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                title: eventTitle,
                teacher : teacher_id,
                teacher_name: teacher_name, 
                start: date.format(),
                end: end.format(),
                allDay: false,
                color: eventColor
            });
        },

        
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
            console.log(event.id);
            deleteEventFromDB(event.id,event.teacher_name);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event.id);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
        },

    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you again for anyone who is response

Comment: @SharanDeSilva absolutely true. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It should not. Still, you will face an undefined error since the property id not resolved.

Comment: what is your suggestion?  There seems to be no problem for now.

Comment: Does this code works.? **eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
            console.log(event.id);
            deleteEventFromDB(event.id,event.teacher_name);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event.id);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
        },**
.. So weired..!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your process for adding events is flawed - you're adding an event to the calendar without waiting for the server to send you a valid ID for it. So that event can never be deleted or updated in the server by clicking on it in the calendar. It has no relationship to the event recorded in the database.

You have to send the event data to the server *first*, get back the auto-generated ID in the response, and then record that as part of the event object you pass into the fullCalendar "renderEvent". If you don't do that, then if you try to update or delete that event, it has no ID which the server would recognise.

Comment: No problem. If my guidance helped, please remember to mark the answer as "accepted", thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

**`event`** object in `eventClick()` doesn't have **`id`** property, Change `id` as `_id`

```
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
            deleteEventFromDB(event._id,event.teacher_name);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
        },
```

Comment: If no ID is specified in the event object, this will be a fullcalendar-generated event ID. It is very unlikely to match the ID of the event in the server-side database. You haven't really thought this through. The event can easily have an "id" property, but it needs to be specified when the event is originally provided by the server. The correct solution is to get the server to supply the ID, so that it can be used again when updating and deleting.

Comment: All the events in fullcalender will have the unique identifier for that event also that goes in _id property. Nothing related to server-side.

Comment: Exactly, that's my point. What do you suppose will happen when you pass this fullCalendar event ID to "deleteEventFromDB"? That ID made by fullCalendar is unrelated to the ID of the event in the database. So how is it supposed to delete the correct event from the database at the same time?

Comment: I think @SharanDeSilva is right. I think the problem might be related to synchronization.

Comment: @HayreddinTüzel No, Sharan is completely wrong. Read my last comment on this answer, and also my last comment on your question. It's nothing to do with "syncing" either, whatever you mean by that. When you add an event, you have to send it to the server _first_, get back the auto-generated ID in the response, and then record that as part of the event object you pass into the fullCalendar "renderEvent". If you don't do that, then if you try to delete that event, it has no ID which the server would recognise.

Comment: @ADyson Ok, I will try it. Thanks for now.

Comment: @HayreddinTüzel You are confusing server unique id with the event id. Also that is not the better idea to keep the event id as the primary key in your server.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva the fullCalendar internal event ID is meaningless in this context. The events have to be related to the server ID, otherwise updates and deletes cannot happen. I apologise for being direct but unfortunately you are talking total nonsense. If anything, it's your intervention which is the confusing thing. The `_id` property is entirely unhelpful in this situation. It will not identify the correct event in the database in order to successfully update or delete the event. Please delete this answer, it doesn't provide a workable solution